# ORA-12805:parallel query server died unexpectedly

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I have a PL/SQL script like this...

```
DECLARE
      CURSOR curs_delete
      IS      
         SELECT cus_num
          FROM dob.cust_table GROUP BY cust_num HAVING COUNT(*)>1;                
      TYPE row_cust_num IS TABLE OF dob.cust_table.cust_num%TYPE;      
      col_cust_num row_cust_num;
   BEGIN
      OPEN curs_delete;
      LOOP
         FETCH curs_delete
         BULK COLLECT INTO col_cust_num LIMIT 10000;
         EXIT WHEN col_cust_num.EXISTS (1) = FALSE;
         FORALL i IN 1 .. col_cust_num.LAST
            DELETE FROM cust_table 
             WHERE cust_num = col_cust_num (i);
             COMMIT;
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE curs_delete;
END;
```

This query returns `ORA-12805:parallel query server died unexpectedly` error. I'm not sure why it is happening. The select query in cursor returned around 415 records when i got this error.

Anyone understand why this error comes up?

Comment: Too vague and speculative to put it as an answer, but anyway: Commiting within a cursor loop might invalidate the cursor. Try to take out the `COMMIT` of the inner loop and see if it improves the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem for your DBA to resolve, as there are a large number of possible causes.  Somebody needs to look in the Alert Log and check for trace files in the `bdump` directory for diagnostic info.

In the meantime, if you have only 415 records to delete you should just use straight SQL:

```
DELETE FROM cust_table
WHERE cust_num in (SELECT cus_num           
                   FROM dob.cust_table 
                   GROUP BY cust_num HAVING COUNT(*)>1);
```

Comment: Agreed. This (simple SQL) is what i'm using for now. I'm concerned about the error which i get with cursor, will check with DBA too.